# Using SQL to Find Employee Time-To-Level-Change

Tags: sql

I am trying to find a means of determining how long it takes for employees to level up.

I have two tables:

EMPLOYEE_DAILY: Contains a daily snapshot of employee data.

EMP_HISTORY: Contains promotion events, the current (pre-promotion) level, the promotion level, and the date of the promotion.

My original solution was to look at the promotion events in the EMP_HISTORY table, then grab the first date that the employee was at the pre-promotion level in the EMPLOYEE_DAILY table, then subtract that date from the promotion date to determine the time it took the employee to level up.

There is a problem with my method as employees often leave the company and then return (sometimes multiple times) so my query will pull the first date the employee was at the CURRENT_LEVEL if it is from a previous employment cycle (thus inflating the time to level up).

```
WITH LEVEL_DATES AS
(
SELECT
    EMPLOYEE_ID,
    EMPLOYEE_LEVEL,
    MIN(AS_OF_DATE) AS MIN_LEVEL_DATE
FROM EMPLOYEE_DAILY
)
SELECT
    H.EMPLOYEE_ID,
    H.PROCESS_TYPE,
    H.CURRENT_LEVEL,
    H.PROMOTION_LEVEL
    H.EFFECTIVE_DATE,
    LD.MIN_LEVEL_DATE
FROM EMP_HIST H
LEFT JOIN LEVEL_DATES LD
ON H.EMPLOYEE_ID = LD.EMPLOYEE_ID
AND H.PROMOTION_LEVEL != LD.EMPLOYEE_LEVEL
```

Does anyone have ideas on how I can pull accurate time-to-level-change data; where the first date at the pre-promotion level is within the employment interval of the employee. I am working with an Oracle database.

Example scenario:
Employee 1234 was hired on 1/1/2015 at L1
Was promoted to L2 on 3/5/2015
Leaves the company on 4/1/2015
Rehired on 1/1/2017 at L1
Promoted to L2 on 3/1/2017

Example data:

```
EMPLOYEE_DAILY:
EMPLOYEE_ID    EMPLOYEE_LEVEL    AS_OF_DATE
1234            L1               2015-03-02
1234            L1               2015-03-03
1234            L1               2015-03-04
1234            L2               2015-03-05
```

Example data:

```
EMPLOYEE_HIST:
EMPLOYEE_ID  EFFECTIVE_DATE  CURRENT_LEVEL PROMOTION_LEVEL 
PROCESS_TYPE

1234         2015-03-05      L1            L2
PROMOTION
```

I believe my query look at the 3/1/2017 promotion and pull the 1/1/2015 date, but what I really want is a query that will show the time between the individual promotion levels, so  3/5/2015 - 1/1/2015 and 3/1/2017 - 1/1/2017.

Comment: "how long it takes for employees to level up" . . . What does that mean?  Sample data and desired results would clarify what you want to do.  Also tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. I attempted to add the items you recommended.
I am looking for the time it takes between a change in level (in my example, from L1 to L2)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't run this to verify accuracy or correct syntax but you can try:

```
select
  employee_id
  ,earliest_as_of_date as effective_date
  ,prev_employee_level as current_level
  ,employee_level promotion_level
from (
  select 
     employee_id
     ,employee_level
     ,case when lag(employee_id,1) over (order by employee_id, as_of_date) <> employee_id then null -- first row for an employee, can't be a promotion
           when lag(employee_level,1) over (order by employee_id, as_of_date) = employee_level then null -- same level as previous row for this employee, is not a promotion
           else lag(employee_level,1) over (order by employee_id, as_of_date) as prev_employee_level
     ,min(as_of_date) over (partition by employee_id,employee_level) as earliest_as_of_date
  from
    employee_daily
  group by 1,2
) a
where 1=1
  and prev_employee_level is not null
```